Email Sending using PHPMailer is delivered in html code
In Godaddy shared hosting . i am using PHPMailer to send HTML formatted mails, Mail is delivered but in html code not the html formatted mails .
$template = file_get_contents('otpmailcontent.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$template = str_replace("###fullname###",$fullname,$template);
$template = str_replace("###otpcode###",$otp,$template);

$email=$toemail;//change email to receipents email
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;//SMTP authentication should be false
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'none';// Security type should be none 
 
$mail->Host = 'localhost';// SMTP host name should be localhost
$mail->Port = 25;  
 
$mail->setFrom('Sales@domainname.com', 'Signup OTP');     //Set who the message is to be sent from
 
$mail->addReplyTo('donotreply@domainname.com', 'Signup OTP');  //Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addAddress($email);  // Add a recipient
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
                               // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Signup-OTP';
$mail->Body = $template ;
$mail->AltBody = $body;
$mail->isHTML(true);   
if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   echo 'Email Has not Sent';
   exit;
}
 else{
  echo "email sent";
}
}

I have made all the changes, Nothing is working .
Could any experts help would be grealy appreciated.
Thanks
Martin.

Swap the order of $mail->isHTML(true); and $mail->Body = $template ;

done same issue is still persisting

What does the Content-type header show?

cant find the content- type. please let me know where to find .

Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" this is the content type in the mail

In that case, the HTML should be rendered properly, I'm not sure why you're seeing the HTML source code. If you use View Source in the mail reader, what do you see? Are you seeing things like <div> or &lt;div&gt;?

$template seems to be text and it's unclear what $body is. Make sure that $mail->Body is HTML and $mail->AltBody is plain text. If you set AltBody, you shouldn't even need to call isHTML(true).

Yes Barmar this is <div> seeing this not 

Apply htmlspecialchars_decode on $body / $template and let us know the result please. See official documentation
